# Fetched URL and Save to Blobstore: AppEngine (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore, urlfetch

The method below will fetch images and save it GAE blobstore:

```
 public static BlobKey saveFetchedImage(String strUrl, String fileName){
     AppEngineFile file = null;
     FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
     BlobKey blobKey = null;
     try{
         URL url = new URL(strUrl);
         InputStream is = url.openStream ();

         file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("image/jpeg", fileName);
         boolean lock = true;
         FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

         while( is.read(buffer) >= 0)   {
             ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
             writeChannel.write(bb);
         }

         writeChannel.closeFinally();
         is.close();

         blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
     }catch(IOException ex){
         System.out.println("URL: " + strUrl);
         System.out.println("IOException - savedFethedImage: " + ex.getMessage());
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("URL: " + strUrl);
         System.out.println("Exception - saveFetchedImage:" + e.getMessage());
     }

     return blobKey;
 }
```

It works previously when trying to fetch 20 URL of images. A new set of 100 URL of images have error. I'm not sure which cause the error since `"URL: " + strUrl` was not printed.

When the error was thrown, the page redirected to `appspot.com/_ah/upload/someString` showing the error below:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.io.IOException
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:590)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.read(FileServiceImpl.java:539)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.read(FileServiceImpl.java:410)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileReadChannelImpl.read(FileReadChannelImpl.java:73)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:272)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:202)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:278)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:316)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
    at au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader.getNextLine(Unknown Source)
    at au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader.readNext(Unknown Source)
    at dating.admin.UploadProfiles.doPost(UploadProfiles.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 10: 
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1495)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:237)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:101)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:586)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 10: 
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.failure(ApiProxyImpl.java:546)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:784)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:824)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.failure(RpcStub.java:815)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:895)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:798)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1059)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:907)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2255)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2062)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:143)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3117)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:599)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:417)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseOneMessage(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:750)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseMessages(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:634)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.access$100(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:37)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport$1.dataReceived(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:295)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.handleNetworkReadEvent(SocketConnection.java:900)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.access$400(SocketConnection.java:43)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection$NetworkReadHandlerImpl.run(SocketConnection.java:929)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:578)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1002)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:1...(length 8274)
```

Any issues on the code above? I know that `fileService` is still in experimental mode. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

     int bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
     while( bytesRead >= 0)   {
         ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         writeChannel.write(bb);
         bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
     }
```